# error while launching vs code from mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I installed the vs code on mac and tried to launch it from terminal but i get the error on running following commands:

```
(base) singhalm ~ $ mkdir home

(base) singhalm ~ $ cd home

(base) singhalm home $ code .
```

When I run the above  command  I get the following warnings and errors :

```
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)

Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table

Syntax Warning: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...

Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary

Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

Note that I have already followed instructions on setting the 'Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command' in VS code.

I also tried to manually add VS Code to my path by running the following commands on the terminal:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile

export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"

EOF
```

how to debug the problem ?

Comment: What is the output of `which code`?

Comment: When I execute 'code .' then  I get all the syntax  warnings and errors.

Comment: I was asking for the output of “`which code`” when you enter it on the terminal. Because the errors look weird to me.. maybe `code` does not call VS Code.

Comment: It does call vs code. I removed the access to vs code from the $PATH and then I get ' command  not found ' error. Also I tried a different command 'pyenv versions' and I get the same syntax warnings and errors'.